# How to show data from a thread to status bar in QT C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets

I'm currently working on a project where I have threads that handle user requests, I'm tring to find a way so when user send request I show some information about this user and the request on the main widget's status bar (on the server side) how can I do this?

Comment: Signals and slots

Comment: I have this thread (thread handles client tcp requests) inside a server and want to show info about client when I get a request

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call this method to show a message in the status bar:

[void QStatusBar::showMessage(const QString &message, int timeout = 0)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstatusbar.html#showMessage)

This is also a slot, so you can also invoke it through a signal-slot connection if you like.

You will need to parse the data from your [QTcpSocket](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtcpsocket.html) before you can display what you want for sure. You need to connect to this signal for example:

[void QIODevice::readyRead()](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qiodevice.html#readyRead)